# Force CSS styled button to "unhover" (Firefox only)

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I have a link

```
<a href="http://someplace.com/url.htm" class="button">CLICK HERE</a>
```

styled by this CSS

```
.button{
    text-decoration:none; text-align:center; 
    padding:10px 0px; 
    border:solid 1px #000000;
    font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    color:#2b2b2b; 
    background-color:#D6E7F6; 
    display: inline-block;
    width:25%
}
.button:hover{
    background-color:#77AEDC; 
    color:#2b2b2b; 
}
.button:active{
}
```

When I hover over the button it correctly changes color.
When I click the link it opens the correct link.
When I click the browser back button, the button color is still the hover color.

How can I get the button(s) to all "unhover" when the page reloads?
This is only an issue in Firefox (both PC and Android versions).

Here is a sample website showing the issue

http://www.filedropper.com/websitetest_1

If you download and extract that to a folder you can open the htm with firefox and see the issue.

Here is a screen capture of what happens to show what I mean.  When the back button is clicked I want the first button to not be in the hover state.

http://www.filedropper.com/example_2

Adding visited, ie

```
.button{
    text-decoration:none; text-align:center; 
    padding:10px 0px; 
    border:solid 1px #000000;
    font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    color:#2b2b2b; 
    background-color:#D6E7F6; 
    display: inline-block;
    width:25%
}
.button:visited{
    color:#2b2b2b; 
    background-color:#D6E7F6; 
}
.button:hover{
    background-color:#77AEDC; 
    color:#2b2b2b; 
}
.button:active{
}
```

does not help.  Clicking the Firefox back button still leaves the hovered state button there.  And a side effect is that then disables the hover for any button that has already been visited.

Hope that makes everything clear.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Replace first row of CSS code `.button{` to be `.button, .button:visited{`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a.button:visited{
  background-color:#77AEDC; 
  color:#2b2b2b; 
}
```